# Converting a web application into a full screen desktop application on a mac?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

What tools would I use to allow a web application to have an icon on a mac desktop and open up the web application in a complete full screen view and allow all the web based jquery touch and gestures.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to create apps for desktop platform (okay mac) in HTML5.
There exist some apps like [Koala](http://koala-app.com/) & [Brackets](http://brackets.io/) which are made like this.

try these —

http://clintberry.com/2013/html5-desktop-apps-with-brackets-shell/

https://nwjs.io/

https://code.google.com/archive/p/chromiumembedded/

Answer (score 0):

You can try AppJS, it's very easy to port existing HTML,CSS,JS based code to desktop application. You can build applications which can run on Windows, Linux and Mac operating systems.

**http://appjs.com/**

Another framwork is meteor.js
**https://www.meteor.com**